# Connecting 8 PDM microphones via SPI/I2S

Tags: microphone, i2s

I'm working on a project where I need to connect 8 PDM microphones to a Raspberry Pi. My current plan is to use a PCMD3180 to connect to either I2S or SPI input on the Raspberry Pi.

The problem is, I have no idea how to set up ICs and get them recording. The documentation of the chip has a suggested set up for an 8 channel microphone configuration over I2S, but I'm not sure which pins on the pi would connect to which pins listed in the diagram, and I've been led to believe by some colleagues that the native clock on the Raspberry Pi might not be fast enough to poll all 8 microphones.

Currently working with a Pi3, but I have access to a Pi4 if needed.

**PCMD:** https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcmd3180.pdf

**Microphones:**  https://www.adafruit.com/product/4346

UPDATE:
I've connected up the PCMD chip as listen on page 99 of the documentation, but I'm not really sure where to connect pins on the Pi itself. I understand that the SCL and SDA pins route to their respective pins on the Pi, but what about the SHDNZ, FSYNC, BCLK, SDOUT, and GPIO1?
Can I connect both FSYNC and BCLK to GPIO 18 on the pi? From my understanding I may have to route the FSYNC signal through a frequency divider first in order to get a higher polling rate on all 8 microphones.
Can SHDNZ be connected to any GPIO pin on the Pi so long as it's addressable? And what about the SDOUT and GPIO1?

I got tossed into the deep end of this project with very little background knowledge on IC and Raspberry Pi usage so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please dont cross post! https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/640188/connecting-8-pdm-microphones-to-a-raspberry-pi-xpost-from-raspberry-pi So remove one of the postings or they both can be rejected.